# Linux: View and kill disowned process

Tags: linux, bash, process

I have started a program in Linux using `&` and `disown`.
I wish to see if it is still running and possibly to kill it.

I started the process with commands like these:

```
(env)bash-4.2$ python manage.py update_rollups &

[1] 29144

(env)bash-4.2$ disown
```

I can no longer find it with `ps aux`, nor kill it based on the pid `29144`.
I want to know if the process is still running (under `init`?).

I hope you can help!

Comment: Welcome on Super User. Give feedback to the answerers, remember that you can [edit] your own question, upvote, downvote the answers and choose one of them if you think it solves your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### In brief

With `&` and `disown` you do not change the PID <sup>[[1](http://www.linfo.org/pid.html)]</sup> of the process.
If you do not see it in the `ps -p <YOURPID>` output, it is not any more running.
You can *over-check* it with an additional `echo $?` <sup>[[2](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXSREF)]</sup> after the `ps` (or `kill`) command, checking if the program exits with an exit code different from `0` (typically `1`).

#### Understanding your commands.

- **Background**: when you launch the command with the final `&` you send it in background.
  This means that:

  - It is present in the job list of your shell (in your example is the number `[1]` and you can refer to it as `%1`; (try the command `jobs`).
  - You can bring it in foreground and in background with `fg` and `bg`.
  - It is (still) *"owned"* by the (linked to the parent) shell: if the shell receives a `SIGHUP` signal, it will send a `SIGHUP` signal to the process too.

    ```
    $ sleep 1h &
    [1] 10795
    $ jobs
    [1]+  running           sleep 1h & 
    $ ps -l -p 10795       
    F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
    0 S  1000 10795  8380  0  80   0 -  3107 hrtime pts/57   00:00:00 sleep
    ```
- **Disown**: with the command `disown` you remove the job from the shell's job list, but you do not change its PID.

  ```
  $ disown
  $ jobs
        # <---- No jobs
  $ ps -l -p 10795
  F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
  0 S  1000 10795  8380  0  80   0 -  3107 hrtime pts/57   00:00:00
  ```

  Note the same PPID (the shell still exists).
  Now we kill the shell.

  ```
  $ kill 8380   # Here we kill the shell 
  $ ps -l -p 10795
  F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
  0 S  1000 10795  5339  0  80   0 -  3107 hrtime pts/57   00:00:00 sleep
  ```

  There is another `PPID`, the `5339`, that with another invocation of `ps`, `ps -p 5339`, you will discover to be an `init` instance:

  ```
  $ ps -p 5339
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  5339 ?        00:02:20 init
  ```

---

#### `pstree`: a quicker way.

You can see with `pstree` more quickly.

Before the `disown` and *kill the bash* commands:

```
$ pstree -s -p 10795 
init(1)───lightdm(1199)───lightdm(5259)───bash(8380)───sleep(10795)
```

After the `disown` and  *kill the bash*:

```
$ pstree -s -p 10795 
init(1)───lightdm(1199)───lightdm(5259)───init(5339)───sleep(10795)
```

<sub>**Note:** of course all the PIDs in your case will be different...</sub>

Comment: extremely thorough answer and exactly what I needed.

Comment: @jimh Thank you. Glad that you liked it.

Answer (score 5):

If it's not in `ps auxf`, then it's not running. If you run `kill 29144` and get "No such process", that also means the process is not running.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the process with ps auxf, or could it be hidden in one of these?


WEB0117  32409  0.3  0.2 583004 39360 ?        Sl   12:49   0:01  \_ WEB0117         -k start

(WEB0117 is the user Im running as)

Answer (score 4):

Each process has a folder in the `/proc` filesystem with it's `pid`. If the folder doesn't exist, the process isn't running.

For example

```
/proc/29144/
```

you can view the process `commandline`

```
cat /proc/29144/cmdline
```

example output:

`/usr/sbin/smbd`

or check the process file status

```
stat /proc/29144/exe
```

example output:

```
File: /proc/29144/exe -> /usr/sbin/smbd
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 78497       Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-04-07 12:18:01.719011505 +0200
Modify: 2017-04-07 12:18:01.369010535 +0200
Change: 2017-04-07 12:18:01.369010535 +0200
 Birth: -
```