# How is this Windows program ignoring my output redirection?

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection

This program [Lunar IPS](https://fusoya.eludevisibility.org/lips/) (which create binary patch files) is seemingly ignoring my redirection to null. I'm invoking:

```
"Lunar IPS" -CreateIPS output.ips input1.txt input2.txt > nul 2>&1
```

And it gives me a load of output anyway:

```
Original file: \input1.txt
Modified file: \input2.txt
Patch Creation Complete! : The IPS patch was successfully created!
```

I want to know either how to do this myself, or (preferably) how to prevent this program from ignoring my redirection.

Note that compared to other similar questions, this one actually does try redirecting both stdout and stderr.

Comment: It may not be the same application running as that which receives the initial command line. Just a guess, but “Lunar IPS.exe” or whatever, might start another application. Or it might restart itself if you aren’t running as admin.

Comment: Redirection only applies to the standard input, standard output, and standard error files/devices.  If the application is opening & writing to a specific file (other than stdout), then no redirection is possible.  IOW if *no* destination filename is specified, where does the program's output go?  Or does it complain that there's no filename specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was in *nix then it would be like in this question: [*How/why does `ssh` output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?*](https://superuser.com/q/1557557/432690) The answer is: it uses `/dev/tty`.

AFAIK the Windows "equivalent" is [`CONIN$`/`CONOUT$`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) [emphasis mine]:

> The `CreateFile` function enables a process to **get a handle to its console's input buffer and active screen buffer, even if `STDIN` and `STDOUT` have been redirected**. To open a handle to a console's input buffer, specify the `CONIN$` value in a call to `CreateFile`. Specify the `CONOUT$` value in a call to `CreateFile` to open a handle to a console's active screen buffer. `CreateFile` enables you to specify the read/write access of the handle that it returns.

I'm not sure if the program in question does exactly this, but I believe it's a possibility. I don't know how to prevent a program from using `CONOUT$` nor how easy or hard it is (if possible at all). In Linux there is [`setsid`](https://superuser.com/a/1430883/432690), but I don't know Windows well enough to give you a similar solution.